# How to fix the "payment transaction failure" issue in onepage?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, javascript, payment-methods

After I installed the following patches: SUPEE-6285-1.9.1v2, SUPEE-6482-1.9.1.1, SUPEE-6788-1.9.1.1, SUPEE-7405-1.9.1.1, my website's onepage checkout payment is not working.

Entered debit Card/Credit Card details in onepage checkout and then clicked "Place Order" but no error and the page stays as it is... received an email titled "payment transaction failure".

I got the following errors in system.log file.

```
2016-03-07T19:31:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): GBP - GBP
2016-03-07T19:31:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): GBP - GBP
2016-03-07T19:31:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): GBP - GBP
2016-03-07T19:31:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): GBP - GBP
2016-03-07T19:31:29+00:00 DEBUG (7): GBP - GBP
2016-03-07T19:31:29+00:00 DEBUG (7): GBP - GBP
2016-03-07T19:31:29+00:00 DEBUG (7): GBP - GBP
2016-03-07T19:31:29+00:00 DEBUG (7): GBP - GBP
2016-03-07T19:31:32+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: status  in app/code/local/Paymentsense/Pay/Model/Pay.php on line 720
2016-03-07T19:31:32+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: error  in app/code/local/Paymentsense/Pay/Model/Pay.php on line 720
2016-03-07T19:31:32+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: CrossReference  in app/code/local/Paymentsense/Pay/Model/Pay.php on line 720
2016-03-07T19:31:32+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: message  in app/code/local/Paymentsense/Pay/Model/Pay.php on line 720
```

Plz find the other error logs here: [pay.log](https://jsfiddle.net/8wcu9gvs/), [exception.log](https://jsfiddle.net/8yauz1u1/).

This is the line 720 in app/code/local/Paymentsense/Pay/Model/Pay.php

```
return array('status'=>$status,'transaction_id' => time() , 'fraud' => rand(0,1),'message'=>$json['error'],'data'=>$json,'CrossReference'=>$CrossReference,'paymenstatus'=>$message);
```

Here is the file [Pay.php](https://jsfiddle.net/LLL2jLfw/)

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please share the Pay.php code

Comment: Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/LLL2jLfw/

Comment: Hi, This is the pay.log https://jsfiddle.net/8wcu9gvs/ and this is the exception.log https://jsfiddle.net/8yauz1u1/ I have already added the system.log in the question. these 3 logs are there in /var/log/

Comment: Any solution Arunendra? :)